# how to handle download stream

Tags: c#, https, stream, msdtc

I need to download xml file from a secure link, and store the content into database.

Can i use text reader??? or i need to store the file into my local file system first, then read the content from my file system and store into my database?

```
HttpWebRequest downloadRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://line-to-xml-file.xml");
string Content;

                downloadRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
                                              {
                                                  UserName = this._userCredentials.UserName,
                                                  Password = this._userCredentials.Password
                                              };

                downloadRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

                using (HttpWebResponse downloadHTTPResponse = (HttpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream downloadResponseStream = downloadHTTPResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    using (TextReader tReader = new StreamReader(downloadResponseStream))
                    {
                        Content = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
              return Content;
```

Since the remote file is huge, up to 100MB, i can see nothing from debug.
and when i try to save it.

```
using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope()) <--- when comes to this line, exception throws...
{
// perform update, save the content into databse
// send a notification message to message bus, indicate content has been updated
}
```

It complain MSDTC  transaction timeout/cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having it into a stream you should be fine... if you have any problem with that specific stream then you could use a [MemoryStream](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1299037554&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http%3a%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.io.memorystream.aspx&lc=1033&cb=&id=254354) instead of a FileStream and use it the same way. But I hardly doubt this is your case.

I think you should make also sure to open the connection RIGHT BEFORE you are going to save the stream and when you have it completely loaded... You can also play with your [Command.TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property if it is taking really, really long to save, here "A value of 0 indicates no limit" but this should be avoided.
but

Answer (score 0):

There is an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), but if the Xml is already well-formed and you don't need to parse it because your database is just taking it as a blob, or the database engine is going to parse it, you could use whatever.

Depends on your database schema.

Sounds like the database is having trouble inserting it, but need more info.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and its download file method. Just save it locally, use it and delete upon completion of use.

Answer (score 0):

100MB of text is a lot to cram in a table.  Your statement is almost certainly timing out.  Check your context and your SQL command object (if you have one) and increase the timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably set a longer timeout duration to solve the timeout problem, and make sure you call the Complete function

```
using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope(
        TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(1, 4, 3))) // Sets time out to 1 hour 4 minutes and 3 seconds
{
  // perform update, save the content into databse
  // send a notification message to message bus, indicate content has been updated

  trans.Complete();
}
```

as for reading the file, you could possible use WebClient. WebClient allows you to monitor the progress.

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
    {
        UserName = this._userCredentials.UserName,
        Password = this._userCredentials.Password
    };

    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
    wc.DownloadFile("https://line-to-xml-file.xml", "C:\\local.xml");
```

The handler could have log the progress if necessary:

```
    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Log or show the current progress (e.ProgressPercentage or e.BytesReceived)
    }
```

You could use DownloadString instead of Download file if you want the string straight without needing to read off the file again.

```
    wc.DownloadString("https://line-to-xml-file.xml");
```